# Passing data to a facebook iframe app when adding an iframe tab to a page

Tags: facebook, iframe

I've created a Facebook iframe app (NOT a Canvas app) that I'm looking to install on various client's facebook pages. Let's say my iframe is at http://fb.mysite.com/iframe/ . I want to pass a client_id to this app when I'm adding it to a client's FB page, so the contents of the iframe will vary depending on the client. I don't want to create separate apps for each client that would have e.g. http://fb.mysite.com/iframe/?client_id=1 or http://fb.mtsite.com/iframe/?client_id=2 etc.

While testing, I've been adding the app to a page by visting

> ```
> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com
> ```

while signed in as the client and adding the app to their page via the dialog that appears at that link. This is where I'd like to pass the client_id. I've tried both appending e.g. client_id=1, so by visiting

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com&client_id=1

, as well as using the app_data parameter (so, it'd be

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com&app_data={"client_id"%3A1}

) and even generating a signed_request containing app_data (

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com&signed_request=xxxxxx

) but no joy.

When I decode the signed_request that comes through from Facebook at http://fb.mysite.com/iframe/, the app_data value isn't present.

Am I missing something here? Is what I'm trying to do possible? Thanks

Comment: `app_data` can only be passed via external links, not via the page tab icon on the FB page itself – the latter always uses the same address, no matter what page the app is on. You can get the _page id_ out of the `signed_request` however.

Comment: Thanks for the response @CBroe. So, map the page id to my client_id? I had thought of this but didn't really want to do it this way, just not as clean as I'd have liked!

Comment: There is no other way.